# UIPickerView start with selected row in middle

Tags: string, global-variables, swift2, uipickerview, xcode7

When the user selects a state from a  `UIPickerView`, it takes them to a different `viewController` with data for the selected state.  When they hit the  'back' button and go to the `viewController` for the `pickerView` it always starts at the top with the first state, in this case Arizona.  How can I make it already scrolled to the middle and have Tennessee selected for example, if that was the state they originally selected? I'm using Xcode 7 and Swift 2, Thank you!

I have a `UIPickerView` that gets it data from:

```
let pickerData = ["Arizona", "Arkansas", "California","Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia"]
```

When the user selects a state in the `pickerView` it takes that value and adds it to a variable:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    //Takes the selected state and adds it to the variable 'currentState'
    currentState = pickerData[row]
    savedStateGV = currentState
}
```

'savedStateGV' is a Global variable and 'currentState' is a local variable.  Both are `String` types.

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could define an attribute middleOfPicker (an Integer) in your viewcontroller and you could set this attribute in the routine "viewDidLoad" (yourpicker is the IBOutlet-name you gave your picker) using the code sequence:

```
middleOfPicker = pickerData.count / 2
yourpicker.selectRow = middleOfPicker
```

Finally, the action routine of your "back button" then should include the statement:

```
yourpicker.selectRow = middleOfPicker
```

Answer (score 5):

In swift 4

```
    yourpicker.selectRow(middleOfPicker, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```